# Removing all text before a certain character for all variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need to remove all text before the last "/" in a variable's name for every variable in a data frame.

suppose this is the data frame:

```
/98519/name   aa77nf4/color   4//342/year
letters       blue            1995
letters       red             1997
```

I am looking for a command that can simplify this to

```
name        color     year
letters     blue      1995
letters     red       1997
```

Comment: Maybe `sub(".*/","",data)` does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `trimws` with `whitespace` as a `regex` to match characters (`.*`) till the `/`

```
names(df1) <- trimws(names(df1), whitespace = ".*/")
```

---

Or another option is `basename`

```
names(df1) <- basename(names(df1))
```

-output

```
> df1
     name color year
1 letters  blue 1995
2 letters   red 1997
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`/98519/name` = c("letters", "letters"), 
`aa77nf4/color` = c("blue", 
"red"), `4//342/year` = c(1995L, 1997L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: The whitespace technique was a great idea and worked well. However, for some reason I cant get it to work when I try to loop it through on a list of data frames. Any idea why this might be? I've got the list of data frames named "surveys", and I'm trying a for (s in surveys {} loop with the trimws command you provided, but "s" in place of "df1"

Comment: @bricevk i don't know your code on the list.  if your list is `lst1`, you may use `lapply` to loop over the list i.e. `lst1 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) {names(x) <- basename(names(x)); return(x)})`

Comment: I meant `lst1 <- list(df1, df2, ...dfn)`